# Left and right margin on a table row

Tags: html, css, css-tables

How can I set the left and right margin of a table row (or something similar to achieve the same result)? I tried `border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:20px;` but that removed the rows border bottom.

This is what I am trying to create:

[image: http://i54.tinypic.com/eqce83.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible with tables.

Here it is with divs and spans.  I hope you like it:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   div#outer {
    border: 10px solid black;
    width: 30em;
   }
   div#header {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
   }
   div.row {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    clear: both;
   }
   span.left {
    float: left;
   }
   span.right {
    margin-left: 10em;
   }
  </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="outer">
  <div id="header">Some table head text</div>
   <div class="row">
    <span class="left">Col</span>
    <span class="right">Col</span>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <span class="left">Col</span>
    <span class="right">Col</span>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <span class="left">Col</span>
    <span class="right">Col</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But then the bottom border will still go all the way from left to right.

Comment: @AwdEr - Wow this was really hard with tables, perhaps impossible because of the way trs expand to fill their containing tables.  However I put together a self-contained page that uses divs and spans.  Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Ray! Think I will go for this solution.

Comment: It is possible with tables using colspan in the header row, and empty columns in the table body.

Comment: Yes that is true, but this practice is frowned upon because it uses tables for formatting.  Having the first and last columns blank and border-bottom just for the middle td's gives the right look, but horribly violates the separation of content (HTML) and presentation (CSS). I could not do this in good conscience! ;-)  Or perhaps you were thinking of something else?

Answer (score 3):

add a class to the table, then add padding to the left and right.

table class="some-table"

.some-table {
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}

should work.

If it doesnt, then add a class to the left    and attach the padding to the left and right col instead.

Comment: If I have a padding on the table the header wouldn't be 100% wide (have a look at the image). If I set the padding on the left and right td the border-bottom would still go all the way from left to right.

Comment: just for reference, here is the table with the spacing on the bottom border.
http://junk.hostsaba.com/table2.html